# Why do I get an error message when trying to trap a SIGINT signal?

Tags: shell, trap

I am running the script below to automatically download files from a server using lftp. It works except that when it runs I get the error message

```
trap: SIGINT: bad trap
```

If I replace SIGINT and SIGTERM with INT and TERM then it does work, but I don't know if it then achieves the same purpose. This is on Linux Debian 4.9.2-10.

```
#!/bin/sh
login="login"
pass="password"
host="server.server.com"
remote_dir='~/remote/dir'
local_dir="/local/dir"

base_name="$(basename "$0")"
lock_file="/tmp/$base_name.lock"
trap "rm -f $lock_file" SIGINT SIGTERM
if [ -e "$lock_file" ]
then
    echo "$base_name is running already."
    exit
else
    touch "$lock_file"
    /usr/bin/lftp -p 22 -u "$login","$pass" sftp://"$host" << EOF
    set sftp:auto-confirm yes
    set mirror:use-pget-n 5
    mirror -c -P5 "$remote_dir" "$local_dir"
    quit
EOF
    rm -f "$lock_file"
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM
    exit
fi
```

Comment: What user does this code run as? What happens if someone naughty creates `ln -s /etc/passwd /tmp/$base_name.lock` or equivalent?

Answer (score 43):

Drop the `SIG` prefix, just input the signal name:

```
trap "rm -f -- "$lock_file"" INT TERM
```

Not all shells understand/take the input with the `SIG` prefix, `sh` (presumably you are using `dash`) is one of those.

On the other hand, more feature rich shells like `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh` allow `SIG` prefix in front of the signal name.

Comment: Thank you! that is what I tried; I just wanted to make sure it did the same thing.

Comment: @flyingace you could also consider changing your `#!` line to reference `bash` instead of `sh`.

Comment: Using `dash`, huh? I haven't heard of that shell before...